# Hide/Show @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have the following code where I am showing a Name, Surname, checkbox and textbox :-

```
        <td>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.checkBoxListTeamA.Count();i++ )
        {
            <div class="ScorerCheckboxList">
                @Html.HiddenFor(it => it.checkBoxListTeamA[i].PlayerId)
                @Html.Label(Model.checkBoxListTeamA[i].PlayerName)
                @Html.Label(Model.checkBoxListTeamA[i].PlayerSurname)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(it => it.checkBoxListTeamA[i].Checked, new { id="CheckBoxA" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(it => it.checkBoxListTeamA[i].NoOfGoals, new { id="TextBoxA",     style="width:20px;" })
            </div>
            <br/>
        }
    </td>
```

I also have the following Jquery script :-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
        ShowHideTextBox();
        $('#CheckBoxA').click(function (event) {
            alert('clicked');
            ShowHideTextBox();
    });
});

function ShowHideTextBox() {
    if ($('#CheckBoxA').is(':checked')) {
            $('#TextBoxA').attr('visible', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#TextBoxA').removeAttr('visible');
        }
   }
</script>
```

However I am not achieving what I want, ie when the user clicks on a checkbox, I want to display the textbox, and if the checkbox is unticked, then I want to hide the checkbox.

What is wrong with my script?  I am not even getting the click when the checkbox is checked!

Thanks for your help and time

----------------UPDATE JQUERY--------------------------

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
        ShowHideTextBox();
});

function ShowHideTextBox() {
    $('.ScorerCheckboxList :checkbox').click(function () {
        alert('Checked!');
        $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').toggle(this.checked);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues.

First, there is no `visible` attribute. Try using `toggle(bool)` instead, where the `bool` is whether the element should be shown.

Second, you have a `for` loop generating your output, which means you're going to end up with multiple elements with the same id, which is against the rules. Change it to something like `id="CheckBoxA"+i`.

Third, your jQuery won't work after changing the id's, and would have affected more elements than you intended. Try something like this:

```
$('.ScorerCheckboxList :checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Edit - complete javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ScorerCheckboxList :checkbox').click(function() { ShowHideTextBox(this); })
        .each(function() { ShowHideTextBox(this); });
});

function ShowHideTextBox(elem) {
    $(elem).siblings('input[type="text"]').toggle(elem.checked);
}
```

Comment: Jason I have updated my Jquery (updated question) howver it is still not working, I am not even getting the click event

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function ShowHideTextBox() {
    if ($('#CheckBoxA').is(':checked')) {
        $('#TextBoxA').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#TextBoxA').hide();
    }
}
```